# Fluent-bit is truncating and discarding java applications logs

Tags: fluent, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, fluent-bit

I am trying to send logs from AWS EKS to AWS Cloudwatch using Fluent-bit. My fluent-bit configuration in generally is working and most of the logs make it to CloudWatch, but the problem occurs with bigger logs. In the beginning it starts truncating logs and eventually it discards the log record.

```
[2023/12/05 14:10:54] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_remove(): inode=77603133 watch_fd=5
[2023/12/05 14:30:14] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=294805] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
[2023/12/05 14:30:19] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=364675] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
[2023/12/05 14:30:24] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=523322] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
[2023/12/05 14:30:29] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] Discarding massive log record
[2023/12/05 14:30:29] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=836367] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
[2023/12/05 14:30:34] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=554279] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
[2023/12/05 14:30:39] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=731990] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
[2023/12/05 14:30:39] [ warn] [output:cloudwatch_logs:cloudwatch_logs.0] [size=793332] Truncating event which is larger than max size allowed by CloudWatch
```

This is my current setup:

fluent-bit.conf

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush                     5
        Grace                     30
        Log_Level                 info
        Daemon                    off
        Parsers_File              parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server               ${HTTP_SERVER}
        HTTP_Listen               0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port                 ${HTTP_PORT}
        storage.path              /var/fluent-bit/state/flb-storage/
        storage.sync              normal
        storage.checksum          off
        storage.max_chunks_up     128
        storage.backlog.mem_limit 5M
        scheduler.cap             30

    @INCLUDE application-log.conf
    @INCLUDE dataplane-log.conf
    @INCLUDE host-log.conf
```

application-log.conf

```
[INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*
        Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser    java, docker, cri
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     Off
        Refresh_Interval    5
        Rotate_Wait         30
        storage.type        filesystem
        Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*
        multiline.parser    docker, cri
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_cwagent.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     Off
        Refresh_Interval    30
        Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               application.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Labels              On
        Annotations         Off
    
    [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               application.*
        region              ${AWS_REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
        log_stream_name     $(kubernetes['container_name'])-$(kubernetes['pod_name'])
        log_stream_template $kubernetes['container_name'].$kubernetes['pod_name']
        auto_create_group   On
        Retry_Limit         False
```

parsers.conf

```
  parsers.conf: |
    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name                multiline-regex
        type                regex
        flush_timeout       5
        # rules |   state name  | regex pattern                  | next state
        # ------|---------------|--------------------------------------------
        rule      "start_state"   "/(Dec \d+ \d+\:\d+\:\d+)(.*)/"  "cont"
        rule      "cont"          "/^\s+at.*/"                     "cont"
    
    [PARSER]
        Name                docker
        Format              json
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ

    [PARSER]
        Name                syslog
        Format              regex
        Regex               ^(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %b %d %H:%M:%S

    [PARSER]
        Name                container_firstline
        Format              regex
        Regex               (?<log>(?<="log":")\S(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ

    [PARSER]
        Name                cwagent_firstline
        Format              regex
        Regex               (?<log>(?<="log":")\d{4}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[ T]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?!\.).*?)(?<!\\)".*(?<stream>(?<="stream":").*?)".*(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\w*).*(?=})
        Time_Key            time
        Time_Format         %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
```

**What I have tried:**

I have tried sending logs with both plugins `cloudwatch` and `cloudwatch_logs`. But unfortunately on both i gives similar error. I have also used and tryed using built in java parser and several multiline parsers, but no luck. Usually the pod runs for some time and then starts getting these errors. So I might assume something might be related with buffer memory or something?

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How did you fix it? Please answer your question to help others.

Answer (score 0):

By now I have solved the problem.

The parsers worked all good. The error was related, that one of our pods logged out huge log at every half hour.(14:30, 15:30, 16:30 etc..)

Although I figured out the error, it was hard to figure out which log line exactly gets truncated as there are a lot of incomming logs. To figure this out I had to use lua script.

Here is my solution, that printed out to logs that were being truncated or discarded.

```
fluent-bit.conf: |
[SERVICE]
    Daemon                    Off
    Flush                     2
    Grace                     5
    Log_Level                 warn
    Parsers_File              parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server               ${HTTP_SERVER}
    HTTP_Listen               0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port                 ${HTTP_PORT}
    storage.path              /var/fluent-bit/state/flb-storage/
    storage.sync              normal
    storage.checksum          off
    storage.max_chunks_up     128
    storage.backlog.mem_limit 5M
    scheduler.cap             30

@INCLUDE application-log.conf
@INCLUDE dataplane-log.conf
@INCLUDE host-log.conf

get-size.lua: |
      function cb_print(tag, timestamp, record)
          if record["log"] ~= nil then
              log_size = string.len(record["log"])
              record["log_size"] = log_size
              -- Print out all logs that are bigger than 255000 bytes
              if log_size > 255000 then
                  print(record["log"])
              end
          end
          return 1, timestamp, record
      end

application-log.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Exclude_Path        /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*
        Path                /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser    java, docker, cri
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_container.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       50MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     Off
        Refresh_Interval    5
        Rotate_Wait         30
        storage.type        filesystem
        Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}

    [INPUT]
        Name                tail
        Tag                 application.*
        Path                /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*
        multiline.parser    docker, cri
        DB                  /var/fluent-bit/state/flb_cwagent.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit       5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines     Off
        Refresh_Interval    30
        Read_from_Head      ${READ_FROM_HEAD}
    
    [FILTER]
        Name                lua
        Match               *
        script              get-size.lua
        call                cb_print

    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               application.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     application.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Labels              On
        Annotations         Off
    
    [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               application.*
        region              ${AWS_REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/containerinsights/${CLUSTER_NAME}/application
        log_stream_name     $(kubernetes['container_name'])-$(kubernetes['pod_name'])
        log_stream_template $kubernetes['container_name'].$kubernetes['pod_name']
        auto_create_group   On
        Retry_Limit         False
```

Hopefully this helps someone to save a lot of time. As it would have for me :)